# Azure REST Service Cost

Tags: azure, azure-management-api, cost-management

Is there any cost associated in sending API calls to the service endpoints mentioned at the following URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/ provided by Azure using Postman?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no cost associated with calling these APIs (at least API calls to manage Azure Resources Control Plane). However, please keep in mind that there's a limit on how many API calls you can make. You can read more about those limits here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-request-limits.